# Proving a function is bounded everywhere

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I'm working on a problem and I'm a bit unsure. I present the unclear part:

> Let $(X,\mathcal{A},\mu)$ be a finite measure space, and let $f$ be an
> $\mathcal{A}$-measurable real-valued function on $X$.
>
> Suppose that
> (i) $f$ belongs to $\mathcal{L}^p(X,\mathcal{A} ,\mu)$ for each
> $p$ in $[1,+\infty)$, and
> (ii) $\sup\{\|f\|_p : 1 \leq p <+\infty\}$ is finite.
>
> I'm supposed to show that $f$ is bounded **everywhere** (since this is
> the author's definition of $\mathcal{L}^\infty(X,\mathcal{A} ,\mu)$).

The norm $\|f\|_\infty$ is defined as the infimum over the positive numbers $M$ such that $\{x\in X : |f(x)| > M\}$ is locally $\mu$-null. Since $\mu$ is finte, locally $\mu$-null is equivallent to $\mu$-null.

I can show that $\|f\|_\infty$ is finite, but I'm not sure about the bounded everywhere part. Any input or thoughts?

**Edit:**

Here is the definition of $\mathcal{L}^\infty(X,\mathcal{A} ,\mu)$
[image]

and here is the problem
[image]

Comment: Bounded **everywhere** is NOT
 the author's definition of $\mathcal{L}^\infty(X,\mathcal{A} ,\mu)$).

Comment: What is it then? Am I hallucinating? He clearly says it is "the set of all bounded ****-valued $\mathcal{A}$-measurable functions on $X$".

Comment: Bounded **almost**  eveywhere.

Comment: Can you point me to the page in the book? (https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-1-4614-6956-8) 

You can see the screenshot of the definition from the book in my post...

Comment: Actually the OP is right the author says clearly that he takes $\mathcal L^\infty$ to be the set of all bounded measurable functions. Moreover he justifies his choice saying this definition makes true some additional properties for this space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question is obviously false. Indeed take $X = [0,1]$ endowed of its Borel sigma algebra and the Lebesgue measure. Take an everywhere bounded function $f$, for instance $f = 0$, then take $N$ to be negligible and with $0$ as accumulation point, for instance $N = \{ 1/n : n \in \mathbb N^* \}$. Then consider $g(x) = f(x) + \frac 1 x 1_N(x)$ (possibly define $g$ as you want for $x = 0$), it is measurable and equal almost everywhere to $f$ which is bounded. The space being endowed of a finite measure $f$ is in any $\mathcal L^p$. Thus $g$ is also in any $\mathcal L^p$ with all its $\mathcal L^p$ norms null but it is not bounded.

To correct the statement you should ask $f$ to be *almost everywhere* bounded, that is there exists $M \in \mathbb R$ such that $\mu(|f| > M) = 0$.

Moreover the author's definition is blatantly false regarding the standard measure theory. From what I know the standard definitions are

- A measurable function is in $\mathcal L^\infty$ if there exists $M > 0$ real such that $|f| \leq M$ almost everywhere
- $||f||_\infty = \inf \{ M > 0 : \mu(|f| > M) = 0 \}$

**Edit**: After having a look at your reference I realize that your definition is not a total non sens. My apologize for judging too fast. This said you can notice that my counter-example works with the definitions of your book so the question contains indeed a mistake.

I really don't understand this choice of definition for $\mathcal L^\infty$. With this choice you don't have that when $f \in \mathcal L^\infty$ and $g$ is measurable and null a.e., $f+g \in \mathcal L^\infty$, and you don't have that any measurable function is in $\mathcal L^\infty$ if and only if $||f||_\infty < \infty$. Moreover the author claims that his definition of $||\cdot||_{\infty}$ (using locally null sets and not null sets) makes it possible to have an isometry $L^{\infty} \rightarrow (L^1)' $ and that it is not possible with the classical definition. This is false, for clarity denote

- $\mathcal L^\infty$ the set of almost surely bounded functions and $L^\infty$ its quotient with the a.e. equality relationship
- $||f||_{L^\infty} = \inf \{ M > 0 : \mu(|f| > M) = 0 \}$
- $||f||^*_{L^\infty} = \inf \{ M > 0 : \{|f| > M\}~\mathrm{loc}~\mu~\mathrm{null} \}$
- $\mathcal M $ the set of all measurable functions $X \rightarrow \mathbb R$
- $B(X,\mathbb R)$ the set of bounded functions $X \rightarrow \mathbb R$
- $||f||_{B(X,\mathbb R)} = \sup_{x \in X}|f(x)|$

Then discover that what the author calls the $\infty$-Lebesgue space is $\mathcal B(X, \mathbb R) \cap \mathcal M$ that is endowed of the norm $||\cdot||^*_{L^\infty}$. There are also the inequalities
$$
||f||^*_{L^\infty} \leq ||f||_{L^\infty} \leq ||f||_{B(X,\mathbb R)}.
$$
The Banach spaces theory tells you that from these inequalities and the vector space $\mathcal B(X, \mathbb R) \cap \mathcal M$ being complete under those $3$ norms, these norms are in fact equivalent. This means that from a topological point of view these three norms are undistinguishable.

Now remember I claimed that something the reference says is false. The author says that proposition 3.5.5 is false when $(\mathcal B(X, \mathbb R) \cap \mathcal M, ||\cdot||_{L^\infty}^*)$ is replaced by $(L^\infty,||\cdot||_{L^\infty})$, this means that the map
$$
T : (L^\infty, ||\cdot||_{L^\infty}) \ni f \longmapsto \langle \cdot, f \rangle_{L^2} \in (L^1)'
$$
is not an isometry. I claim it is, indeed take $f \in L^\infty$, then forall $g \in L^1$ you get by triangle inequality and Hölder
$$
|T(f)g| \leq ||fg||_{L^1} \leq ||f||_{L^\infty}||g||_{L^1}
$$
so that the operator norm of $Tf$ is such that $||Tf|| \leq ||f||_{L^\infty}$. Now to get the equality do as done in the proof the author gives: without loss of generality we can assume $||f||_{L^\infty} > 0$. Take $||f||_{L^\infty} > \epsilon > 0$ and remark that
$$
A_\epsilon : \{ |f| > ||f||_{L^\infty} - \epsilon \}
$$
has positive measure. Then consider $g = sgn \circ f   \times 1_{A_\epsilon}$, is has $L^1$ norm $\mu(A_\epsilon) > 0$ so
$$
|T(f)g| = \left | \int_X f(x) sgn(f(x)) 1_{A_\epsilon}(x) d\mu(x) \right| = \int_{A_\epsilon}|f| d\mu \geq (||f||_{L^\infty} - \epsilon)\mu(A_\epsilon) = (||f||_{L^\infty} - \epsilon) ||g||_{L^1}
$$
shows the isometry.

Comment: FYI, the author is Donald Cohn. This is a pretty substantial error on his part then.